# Finding Specific file name in Folder and deleting it

Tags: batch-file, window

There is a folder called "db", it's the database with info.

I want the player to be able to put the ID ( All files are named, 1, 2, 3)
All files have it ID, I want the player to be able to delete a specific ID.txt

Example:

```
:dldb
cls
echo.
echo Insira o ID do arquivo que deseja remover.
set /p idrem=ID: 
if exist "db\%idrem%" (
    echo Arquivo com o ID %idrem%, foi encontrado, deletando..
    del /s "db\%idrem%"
)
else (
    echo Arquivo com o ID: %idrem%, nao foi encontrado.
)
pause
cls
goto menu
```

But it's always saying "Could not find" | PT-BR : "nao foi encontrado"

It's portuguese, i'm a brazilian, but I think it's easy to understand, just ignore the echo, but it's always saying that couldn't find the specific ID, that would be "1", so, "db\1", And there's a txt named 1.

If you can not understand please reply, I'm trying. ( I'm still learning English )

Comment: Already solved, sorry, I added *txt after %idrem%, like that:

if exist "db\%idrem%"*txt

Comment: Maybe you can put it as an answer?